# Clickable image layers with transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two images with transparent background.
I added both to the layout view.

I need to assign an onClickListener to each image.

The problem is that only the topmost image is firing the click event (is like if the top most image cover the rest and don't care about its transparent background). Both images are .png with transparent background

Here is the code:

```
    ImageView img1, img2;

    RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

    bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image1);
    bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image2);

    img1 = new ImageView(this);
    img1.setImageBitmap(bm1);
    l.addView(img1);

    img2 = new ImageView(this);
    img2.setImageBitmap(bm2);
    l.addView(img1);

    img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //code to process when img1 is clicked
        }
    });

    img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //code to process when img2 is clicked
        }
    });
```

In this example, only img2 is firing the event.
I need that both img2 and img1 can fire their events.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: U can combine code which process img1 to img2 ...

Comment: img1.setonclicklistener(new onclicklistener()

Comment: That's what I did, the problem is that the transparent background is considered part of the image and I don't want that.

Comment: When you click one should both of them images execute their onClick methods? Or do you somehow want to distinguish which ImageView was clicked?

Comment: I need to distinguish which ImageView was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If the transparent background of one image covers the second, then the first will respond as being clicked, because the transparent background is counted as part of the image.

Perhaps the simplest answer would be a little bit of photo-editing to remove some of the transparent background. Crop the images a bit.

Comment: The thing is that they are not square images (imagine three hexagons one stick to another in a triangle shape). Is there any way of not considering transparent background in click event? I did the same in GameMaker and it worked like a charm...